# Validation of a numerical simulation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to test the order of accuracy of a numerical method used to solve a complex physical phenomena.

If the analytical solution is known, the calculation of the order of accuracy is easy. It suffices to calculate the differences between the exact solution and the numerical solutions for different space steps.

As the analytical solution is not known, I compare between the solutions for two consecutive space steps and for different steps: for example, for a 1D model posed on the interval $[0,1]$, we vary $n$ (the number of subintervals) between $N_1$ and $N_2$ then I calculate the error as $\|u_n-u_{n+1}\|$, where $u_n$ is the numerical solution with $n$ subintervals.

My question is how can I calculate $\|u_n-u_{n+1}\|$? In fact, $u_n$ is defined on a grid different from the grid on which $u_{n+1}$ is defined.

Comment: If the fine grid contains the coarse grid, you could simply estimate on the nodes of the coarse grid. Not perfect, but easy to implement. The more accurate way is a projection from one grid to another. E.g. in multigrid methods that is done by either restriction (fine⇒coarse) or prolongation (=interpolation) (coarse⇒fine).

Comment: Another way to test the code / method / accuracy settings when no analytical solution is known is to construct an analytical solution to a slightly different problem. For example if your equation is $\mathcal{L}u = f$ for some source $f$ and some operator $\mathcal{L}$ then you can choose a 'solution' $u$ (compatible with the boundary conditions you want) and then compute what source $f$ this corresponds to and then let the code solve this slightly different equation instead.

Comment: @P.Siehr. How can I do the restriction if the fine grid does not contain the coarse grid ?
For the prolongation, may be I lose accuracy order by the interpolation. No? Is the interpolation (of order at least 2) is easy to do in a 2D or 3D grid ?

Comment: I can't give you a satisfying answer - sorry. That is why I wrote a comment. I remember that in the case of the mutligrid method there were some convergence issuse when using bilinear interpolation instead of the $L^2$-projection (as restriction.)

Comment: Btw. Why do you have different grids? Usually it is easier to refine a corse grid, instead of creating a completely new grid.